# Why do the following two code snippets result in different compilation output with MSVC, while same with gcc?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-c++, compilation

This question is about why it seems that MSVC fails a very basic optimization with which gcc has no struggle. I'm wondering whether I missed something here and what the reason could be.

The following code snippet:

```
#include <vector>

struct X {
    int x;
    double y;
};

void for_1(std::vector<X>& x) {
    for (auto& y : x) {
        y.x = 1;
    }
}

void for_2(std::vector<X>& x) {
    for (auto it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++ it) {
        it->x = 1;
    }
}
```

When compiled with MSVC with optimization on (-O2), it compiles the two functions to different assemblies (Note the additional `mov` in `for_1`. For full output, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ziBWi3)):

```
x$ = 8
void for_2(std::vector<X,std::allocator<X> > &) PROC ; for_2, COMDAT
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        cmp     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx+8]
        je      SHORT $LN3@for_2
        npad    7
$LL4@for_2:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 1
        add     rax, 16
        cmp     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx+8]
        jne     SHORT $LL4@for_2
$LN3@for_2:
        ret     0
void for_2(std::vector<X,std::allocator<X> > &) ENDP ; for_2

x$ = 8
void for_1(std::vector<X,std::allocator<X> > &) PROC ; for_1, COMDAT
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rcx+8]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        cmp     rax, rdx
        je      SHORT $LN3@for_1
        npad    4
$LL4@for_1:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 1
        add     rax, 16
        cmp     rax, rdx
        jne     SHORT $LL4@for_1
$LN3@for_1:
        ret     0
void for_1(std::vector<X,std::allocator<X> > &) ENDP ; for_1
...
```

But with gcc 9.2 (-O3), the output are the same:

```
for_1(std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> >&):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        cmp     rax, rdx
        je      .L1
.L3:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 1
        add     rax, 16
        cmp     rdx, rax
        jne     .L3
.L1:
        ret
for_2(std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> >&):
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        cmp     rax, rdx
        je      .L6
.L8:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 1
        add     rax, 16
        cmp     rdx, rax
        jne     .L8
.L6:
        ret
```

To me, it seems pretty rudimentary to optimize both functions to the same assemblies, but MSVC for some reason fails here. Why is this? Am I missing something?

Comment: They are, after all, two different compilers. As to why one does something a particular way is up to the compiler designer. So it would be speculation as to why it does what it does.

Comment: @lurker Because this looks like a very basic optimization, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: What happens when you take overlapping instructions, branch prediction etc into account?  it's almost impossible (as a human) to generate optimised machine code for non-trivial problems.

Comment: So you think these to asm code are **very** different? They are just marginally different. As @lurker and Richard say, what code is emitted is compiler dependant...and there could be very good reasons for one not to use what seems an optimisation for the other.